# Bitwise AND/OR with a varbinary(255) in mysql

Tags: mysql, varbinary

I have the following field in a mysql table:

```
bitmap  varbinary(256)
```

I want perform a bitwise AND on this field. I tried:

```
select id, Hex(bitmap) from mytable;
| 735 | 1D1BA8284000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 736 | 1D1BACA80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |

select Hex(bitmap & 0xFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) from mytable

| 735 | 0                                                                                       |
| 736 | 0                                                                                       |
```

Mysql always give 0 even then my columns are non-zero

Comment: That doesn't look like it's a direct dump from mysql, as you're still displaying the ID in the bottom output despite not selecting it. That makes me wonder what else about the query isn't exactly what you wrote. Out of interest, what do you get if you use OR intead of AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support bitwise operations on whole `varbinary()` fields.

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html):

> MySQL uses BIGINT (64-bit) arithmetic for bit operations, so these operators have a maximum range of 64 bits.

You *might* be able to perform operations on single bytes at a time by extracting them with `substr()` and then `concat` that result with the remaining bytes that originally wrapped the byte of interest, i.e.

```
SELECT CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTR(bitmap, 1, 1)) & 0xff || SUBSTR(bitmap, 2)
```

obviously this doesn't scale well...